# restrict opening a network drive

Tags: java, database, swing, ms-access, network-drive

guys i have my project based on java-swing. Its basically like information sharing over the intranet where the users are connected to each other wireless/wireline. The database is on the network drive. All the machines have the app installed. Everybody is able to execute the database. I am having the following issues:

---

1. everybody is able to view the folders(including database) in the network drive. How do i set the permissions such that the app is able to access the database but the user is unable to view the network drive folders.
2. If anybody try to execute the database simultaneously, it throws an SQL error. how to handle that? should i put some delay when such exception is caught ?

PS- am using Ms Access

urgent help required.. 
Thanks in advance guys.. would be great help... ! :)

Comment: Use a database that multiuser ready.

Comment: and how to set the permissions ?

Comment: Better to use a database server like MySQL or PostgreSQL, or even better, some kind of web access layer that supports something like JSON

Comment: Basically MS Access is simply not made for multiuser access, so use the things suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: @Markus re: "Basically MS Access is simply not made for multiuser access" -- Wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> everybody is able to view the folders(including database) in the network drive. How do i set the permissions such that the app is able to access the database but the user is unable to view the network drive folders.

If people are going to be accessing a shared .accdb or .mdb file on a network drive then obviously they have to be able to "see" it and "read" it. If they need to be able to update that database then they need "write" permissions on the file as well.

Note, also, that for multiuser access of a shared Jet/ACE database file to work properly *all* users must have `Create File` permissions on the **folder** in which the shared file resides. This is because they need to be able to create the lock file (.laccdb or .ldb) in that folder. (For a more detailed explanation see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239970/how-to-enable-1-user-to-update-the-database-while-allowing-others-to-only-read-i/15735367#15735367).)

As for restricting access to all of the other files and folders on the network share, that is a matter of setting the appropriate permissions on those objects *on the server*. There's no sense in fiddling with your application code to try and restrict access if they can just open an Explorer window and browse around the network share that way.

> If anybody try to execute the database simultaneously, it throws an SQL error. how to handle that?

Please edit your question to let us know what the error *actually says*.