# "operation must use an updateable query" after deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, database, ms-access

I have created a desktop application in C# (WPF) with an Access 2010 database, I have also created setup program for it. My problem is that when I installed it on my PC it works fine, but when I install it on some other PC then it fails with an Exception like

"Operation must use an updateable query"

I have searched for it and every answer I found suggested that it was a permissions issue. I have tried to give full access to database folder but still I get the same error, I have tried to resolve it for last two days but I still haven't found a solution.

Comment: Does your setup program distribute the database file as well? If so, is it putting the database file in the same folder as your executable file(s)? ...someplace like `C:\Program Files\yourApp`?

Comment: Yes my database file is in the same folder where other executable files. for your reference I have Upload my exe file in mentioned link

Comment: Yes my database file is in the same folder where other executable files. for your reference I have Upload my exe file in mentioned link http://www.4shared.com/file/EDzIi7T9/DailyExpense.html

Comment: Have you tried running your app as administrator?

Comment: If this exception is occuring when a query is being run, does the table in that query have a primary key? I've encountered this error previously while running an update query on a table that did not have a primary key

Comment: Yes in Register Table I had Add the ID as a primary key..

Answer (score 0):

If your installer is placing the database file in the same folder as the executable file(s), e.g., `C:\Program Files\myApp\` then regular users will only have read-only access to the database:

[image: myData.png]

Even if your installer modifies the permissions on the database *file*, regular users will still have read-only access to the database because they have read-only access on the *folder*...

[image: myApp.png]

...and you definitely do NOT want to open up read-write access on that folder to regular `Users`. (For details on the effect of file/folder permissions on Jet/ACE databases, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239970/how-to-enable-1-user-to-update-the-database-while-allowing-others-to-only-read-i/15735367#15735367).)

Instead, your installer should be putting the database file into a folder where regular users normally have read-write access, perhaps somewhere under `%PUBLIC%`.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply but I have doubt in it because I have already given all the permission and even if I installed it on MY other drive like D drive then also same exception occurred.