# operation must use updateable query Vb.net Desktop application Error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I deployed my Vb.net desktop application. but I'm getting error on Access datbase(.mdb file) that

> operation must use updateable query

I'm using Access .mdb file for storing data.I got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989611/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-after-deployment) to solve this problem, but it's the manual way to do it. So when my app is installed on client machine then they have to do it manually.

What else is the solution that avoid the manual way?

please help
I'm getting stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is installing a copy of the database on each computer as is implied by the link, are you sure that's what you want? No data will be shared between each computer. Otherwise, what the link is saying to do, is rethink the location of the database, and get the installer to put it somewhere with read and write permission, not the application directory.

Comment: Hi @Makita,I have to give the full control to the directory of installation.I did it while creating installer,give an full permission(read,write) to the directory where database is located(i.e. .mdb file)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you created your .MSI file through Visual Studio Setup. I have also encountered your problem and the solution I used is to change its default directory from `[Program Files]` to `[WindowsVolume][ProductName]` - it will be installed through `C:\YourApp\`. Since the error is due to the *user* unable to write on the database, I tried to change its directory from program files and installed it again. It works for me.