# C# - OleDb Exception while running published .exe

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010, oledb

I'm working on a C# project. While running it in VS2013, it shows no error. I'm using MS Access 2010. But after publishing the project, clicking any button that involves database process, .exe application shows OleDbException.

`OleDbException : Use updateable query.`

But it works perfectly on VS2013.

**My Connection String :** `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Datasource=|DataDirectory|\\Resources\\GreenTrends.mdb;Persist Security Info=True`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the user running the process has appropiate read/write permissions to the database file. The error message as such can be a bit misleading since its often missing permissions causing the error. For more information please refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991464/1137115)