# how to read an Access database when it's open by another person

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on a website application that reads data from an Access db. It works fine until someone opens the database to work on it (e.g., write new record...). When this happens, the connection is interrupted and a message like "database in use" appears.

I understand that Access has a security file with extension `.ldb` that is created automatically when the `.mdb` is open, so I'm looking to a way to be able to open the database for multiple users. That way, I can check the data from my application and, at the same time, record new data.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The website application does not maintain a continuous connection to the database, so the symptoms you describe could be caused by one of the following:

- When "someone opens the database to work on it" they open it in Exclusive mode, which prevents other users/processes from opening it at the same time.
- When "someone opens the database to work on it" they do not have "Create File" permission on the ***folder*** in which the `.mdb` file resides. This prevents them from creating the `.ldb` lock file and can cause other users to be forced to read-only mode or prevent them from accessing the database entirely. (For more details on file/folder permissions for multi-user access, see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239970/how-to-enable-1-user-to-update-the-database-while-allowing-others-to-only-read-i/15735367#15735367).)

Comment: yes, i understand that. but i didn't find a suitable solution for tis problem. i'm thiniking about something to make it work but i'm not sure of it. creating a copy of the original database, linked both and when a change is made, an update will be done.