# Host MySQL on a shared folder

Tags: java, mysql, shared-directory

I am trying to host MySQL Database on the shared location of the organization.
Is there any way through which I can achieve this because I don't have a shared server which will run all the time.

Comment: I don't think that sounds like a good idea with mysql. But you could take a look at SQLite, wich (as far as I know) is basically built for using a file instead of a server.

Comment: Why vote to close? This questions shows a lack of knowledge but that doesn't mean it should be closed; others could easily be confused in the same way as the OP about the intent and function of file sharing and a DBMS. The question is specific (as opposed to too broad) and is definitely about a programming topic; it also has a clear objective answer.

Comment: It sounds like you have file sharing available (e.g., through a [NAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) appliance or similar setup) but you don't have an actual server on which you can install MySQL. Is that a correct assessment?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes it's correct asessment. Just because my organization don't want to manage server I have to use file sharing facility. Please share something which can help on this.

Comment: In that case you need to consider a solution similar to what you asked about in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30705140/2144390).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is a "client-server" database management system (like Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.) so it requires a server on which the centralized database management application (the "database server") can run. The client software for such databases can only "talk to" the application running on the server, and the server application updates the database file(s); the clients cannot update the database file(s) directly.

By contrast, a "peer-to-peer" (sometimes called a "shared-file") database like Microsoft Access does not have a centralized database application. Instead, each client machine has a copy of the database engine that can update the database file(s) directly in a co-operative fashion.

So, you cannot use MySQL without having a MySQL database server running *somewhere*. As for a peer-to-peer solution, refer to your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30705140/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

While I understand what you are doing it is simply a very bad idea and cannot be made to work. Much of the purpose of a DBMS  system (like mySQL) is to handle concurrent access to the data responsibly.

The basic idea of the architecture is to talk (in small messages) to a server software stack that can rapidly access its files and grab the data you need and send it back to you. This server software stack does two things:

1. Negotiates that clients looking at the same data all see a consistent meaningful picture of the data
2. Does all the searching, sorting, indexing etc on the server without sending all this data back and forth across the network.

So if you are using MySQL shared between different client machines you need to have the mysql server running ONCE on the server (as opposed to running on each client accessing a shared drive as you suggest).