# MS Access database locked by Python

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, sqlalchemy-access

I'm writing a dataframe to an MS Access database using Python. It works, but I can't seem to close the connection (i.e. the database is locked by Python).

Here's my code:

```
# imports
import urllib
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# connection
connection_string = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=M:\Larry\Access\test2.accdb;'
    r'ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;'
)
connection_uri = f"access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)}"
engine = create_engine(connection_uri)

# create dataframe
d = {'name':['daryl','other daryl'],'team':['a','b']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# write to database
df.to_sql('test',engine,if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

I tried adding this after the create engine line:

```
conn = engine.connect()
```

and this after the dataframe is written to the database:

```
conn.close()
```

I don't get an error from these additions but the database is still locked. How do I close the connection so that the lock is removed?

Comment: Try disposing engine: `engine_dispose()`

Comment: Is the M: drive mapped to a network share?

Comment: @Parfait - did you mean engine.dispose() ? That worked and the database is no longer locked. Do you want to post that as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: @GordThompson - Yes, the M: drive is a network share.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15735367/2144390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are maintaining a connection instance of the database with engine object, after operations, consider [`Engine.dispose()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#engine-disposal) to release the resource:

```py
...
# write to database 
df.to_sql('test', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

engine.dispose()
```